# Query not returning if there's a minus in the title

Tags: php, pdo, slug

My query doesn't return everything if an min is in the title.

Code:

```
$stmt = $db->runQuery("SELECT all * FROM articles WHERE id = :id AND title LIKE CONCAT(:slug, '%')");

$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':slug', $slug, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Example slug: `test-4-1`

Comment: Please include some more code, where you bind the params, and some examples of whats going in and whats coming out.

Comment: I can't deliver more code as this is an query issue. I edited the post with the params and gives more details of what doesn't work.

Comment: What does `runQuery` do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help,

I fixed it by adding or operators in my query.

```
SELECT all * FROM articles WHERE id = :id AND title LIKE CONCAT('%', :slug, '%') or title LIKE CONCAT('%', :slug2) and id = :id
```

And the new :slug2 paramater:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':slug2', $_get['slug'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Seems like the question is missing some information. Also `PDO::PARAM_INT` wont work with `test-4-1`.

Comment: I'm aware of that, didn't noticed. And which information does it mis? For me nothing.

Comment: The question is about a `-` in the text. This is binding a second value, probably just hiding the real issue, the real issue is unclear though.